# Access private classes in a class library, from a console app c#

Tags: c#, console-application, access-modifiers, class-library

I'm having trouble accessing my private class "inventory" in my class library, from my console application. I have referenced it and i can access "inventory" when its set to public class. Are there any ways to access it, when "inventory" is set to private?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace InventoryManagementDND
{
    class Inventory
    {
```

The error feedback i get from visual studio is inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using InventoryManagementDND;


namespace InventoryRunProgram
{
    class Program
    {            

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int test = 0;
            Inventory I1 = new Inventory();
```

[Solution explorer setup with the class library on top, console app on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiXBP.png)

Comment: So why not make `Inventory` public ?

Comment: Note that it's not private - it's internal. And that's the whole point of things being internal - that you can't see them from other projects. This is a good thing, and you shouldn't try to work around it. If you want to be able to access it from your console app, make it public in your library project.

Comment: Why dou you want it to be private if you need it in another project. The purpose private access modifiere is to limit access by external code.

Comment: Do note the access modifier `internal` is intended to do that

Comment: there *is* a way to do what you are asking - `[assembly:InternalsVisibieTo(...)]` - however: that sounds like the wrong solution here; the *correct* solution would appear to be simply: make the type `public`

Comment: @MarcGravell that trick is really useful with unit tests of classes poorly developed